# How to configure PostgreSQL to accept all incoming connections except postgres / admin

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

My question is how to configure it so that non-admin (non-postgres) accounts can login from the internet but the admin (postgres) user is only allowed from localhost or a limited IP range.  What entries in the `pg_hba.conf` that let me set this up?  I already have set this up in `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I also have added the line to my `pg_hba.conf` to allow log in from the wide open world:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

But now the `postgres` use can log in from any address which is not what I want :(

I have seen a number of places that talk about how to open up PostgreSQL for connections from any address like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host but no questions that open it up and lock down the `postgres` user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             postgres                                trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             postgres        0.0.0.0/0               reject 
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Comment: Ah - I thought it would be something like that.  I searched and searched and could not find "reject" - that makes so much sense given that the rules are processed in order until one matches.